# Eclipse JBoss Tools configuration error

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, eclipse-juno

I am using:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855
```

And offline `Jboss` tools zip file is 
`jbosstools-4.0.0.Final.aggregate-Update-2012-12-06_13-22-08-B136`

I successfully added zip file and it is also connecting to database,see the screenshot
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/jboss.png/

and my hibernate jars are(hibernate-release-4.1.8.Final)

```
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.1.8.Final.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commos-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

In screenshot first exceptions is

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]**

    org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:402)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2155)
        at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$6.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:430)
        at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.getSettings(ConsoleConfiguration.java:428)
        at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:397)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: could not instantiate CacheProvider [org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider]
        at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:66)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:63)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Stack trace?  You won't get much help without it/

Comment: Sir added can u see please

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jboss Tools. Whenever I run into a classnotfound I just copy paste the class that is not found into Google. In this case the first hit was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128233/hibernate-cannot-connect-to-the-db

Comment: @Gimby The link provided by u is not valid.